# Pip + virtualenv + Redhat SCL + proxy = not working

Tags: proxy, python, virtualenv, pip, scl

I am setting up a virtualenv based on Python 2.7 in Redhat Enterprise 6 (which ships with 2.6.x by default).

I installed the SCL 2.7 version of Python and then created the virtualenv:

```
$ scl enable python27 bash
$ cd /my/project
$ virtualenv -v --clear --extra-search-dir=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/ --python=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python virtualenv
$ source virtualenv/bin/acticvate
```

So far so good. The problems started when I tried to run pip behind my institution's proxy:

```
$ pip install Werkzeug --proxy proxy.example.org:3128                       
Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug                                                 
Cleaning up...                                                                 
Exception:                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)                                           
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1085, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)        
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 201, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)                                 
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 554, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)                      
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 671, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)                                                        
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 176, in __call__
    response = self.get_opener(scheme=scheme).open(url)                        
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)                                           
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)                                                              
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)                                                       
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 155, in https_open
    return self.do_open(self.specialized_conn_class, req)                      
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1183, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)         
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1001, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)                             
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)                                                      
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 997, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)                                            
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 850, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)                                                             
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 812, in send
    self.connect()                                                             
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 139, in connect
    match_hostname(self.sock.getpeercert(), self.host)                         
  File "/my/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/backwardcompat/ssl_match_hostname.py", line 61, in match_hostname
    % (hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames))))                              
CertificateError: hostname 'proxy.example.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', 'python.org', 'pypi.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'testpypi.python.org', 'bug>>>s.python.org', 'wiki.python.org', 'hg.python.org', 'mail.python.org', 'packaging.python.org', 'pythonhosted.org', 'www.pythonhosted.org', 'test.pythonhosted.org', 'us.py>>>con.org', 'id.python.org', 'pypi.io'
```

I have seen this issue in other questions but none of these seem to apply to my case.

**Edit:**

E.g. I tried setting environment variables as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468550/pip-not-working-behind-firewall . Other cases were addressing Windows issues.

It may be worth mentioning that this virtualenv won't work if I am not in the scl environment, e.g. if I call `python` enabling the virtualenv but not scl, it will complain that libpython2.7.so.1.0 cannot be found. I don't know if this is bny design, but I expected all the libraries Python 2.7 depends on to be symlinked or copied in the virtualenv. Maybe something I did wrong in the virtualenv installation?

Comment: It would probably be useful to people if you made a little list of questions with this issue and an explanation of why they do not apply to your case.

Comment: Sorry, the message was cut off when I first posted it. I added the information that you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably solved it by now, but it seems that you need to use the trusted host option:

`pip install Werkzeug --proxy proxy.example.org:3128  --trusted-host proxy.example.org`